# Why is the second identical ImageView inside LinearLayout smaller?

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have two ImageViews with the same image source inside LinearLayout, but why the second image is smaller than the first?

This is the source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/background_landscape" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/background_landscape" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot ImageView with smaller image on the second image]

The error can be reproduced clearly on 800x1280 pixel resolution.

How can make both images have the same size with the second image cropped on the right side of the screen. (NOT SCALED DOWN)

Comment: "why the second image is smaller than the first?" -- there isn't room for it at the same size as the first and still have it be inside the parent container. "How can make both images have the same size with the second image cropped on the right side of the screen" -- either crop the image yourself, draw the image yourself on a `Canvas`, or use a negative margin to have the second `ImageView` extend past the boundaries of its container `LinearLayout`. Note that the latter technique only seems to work on Android 4.0+ based on my experiments.

Comment: Ok, I understand your explanation, but I think cropping the image will make the code more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... why the second image is smaller than the first?

Because the first image gets its **real** width due to `wrap_content` value of `layout_width` attribute. And the second image receives the **rest width** (width of layout minus width of first image) from `LinearLayout`, which is obviously smaller, than the real width of the image. That's why it gets scaled down.

> How can make both images have the same size with the second image
>   cropped on the right side of the screen. (NOT SCALED DOWN)

You might use `ScrollView`, which allows children to go out of parent's boundaries.

**Update**: as mentioned by CommonsWare:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="false"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/background_landscape" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/background_landscape" />

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: It would have to be `HorizontalScrollView` (given the image and `LinearLayout` orientation), and that assumes that scrolling is acceptable behavior here.

Comment: @beworker It works for me.
Thank you this is exactly what I want.
But for information, the parent from HorizontalScrollView must be standard layout like LinearLayout because the Hand phone picture will disappear otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Like beworker said the first image is getting its width due to the `wrap_content` and the second image gets the remaining available horizontal space.
Use `android:layout_weight="1"` in both `ImageViews` if you want them each to ocuppy half the available screen width

Comment: Note that the question specifically states that the desired behavior is for the second image to be cropped; your solution will not achieve that.

Comment: Yes, like @CommonsWare said, layout_weight makes the images are scaled down, I don't want to scaled down because I want it as the base infinite background animation.

Comment: Yes @CommonsWare right i kinda read the question a a bit on the diagonal sry